# Interpretting お世話になる職場の方

Tags: meaning, nuances

I have a following sentence:

> **娘がお世話になる職場の方**として
>
> ご近所の母親友達として
>
> 母子共々よろしくお願いします

Context: Person A is mother of a daughter working (recently joined) in the same organization as the Person B this is directed towards. I'd say that this roughly means:

> As a person from the workplace where my daughter is "being taken care of"/working
>
> and as a mother-friend?!? from the neighborhood
>
> I leave both of us in your care.

I am aware of course that お世話になる職場 is likely just a fancy way to say workplace where the daughter is [working or being trained](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60513/meaning-of-%E3%81%8A%E4%B8%96%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-vis-a-vis-place-of-work-or-place-where-someone-is-being-traine). What I'm wondering is does this imply that the person in question (B/方) is the one taking care of/supervising the daughter? I don't think so. I think the idea is that the workplace is doing or the taking care is happening on it, and B is just working there.

So A is more asking for B to "keep an eye" on her daughter, rather than to work her well...

And yeah, I'm also wondering about that 母親友達, is it someone who is a mother and a friend (to A) or might it be more mother of daughter's friend because A's and B's daughters are friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're taking よろしくお願いします too seriously. It's [notoriously difficult to translate](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/yoroshiku-onegaishimasu-meaning/), but basically it's no more than "glad to see you" here. It's a word used to establish/keep a good relationship with someone. Even if B is not going to directly supervise or train A's daughter, or even if B is unlikely to see A's daughter at the workplace, there is nothing wrong saying よろしくお願いします. 母親友達 is also known as [ママ友](https://bangin.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9E%E5%8F%8B-mamatomo/), friends who are also mothers. They often get together and talk about their kids and husbands.

So the loose interpretation would be simply: "You work at my daughter's training site (though you may not have have chances to see/help my daughter), and we will probably share some time since we are neighbors and both mothers. In either terms, I'm glad to see you."

Comment: Ah, yes. She is using this kinda pleasantry because both she and her daughter will kinda be "working" with B. Daughter will be in the same workplace and A and B are moms. Although, I wouldn't associate "glad to see you" with よろしくお願いします. In English that is something I'd use when meeting someone. Here they have just had a length talk at the end of which A uses the above to formally establish the relationship of her and her daughter to B.

Comment: @4thDimension Then please use one of the translation options in the linked page. Or how about something like "Nice meeting you", "I hope we can get along well" or "Let's keep in touch"? As I said, there is no single translation that works regardless of the situation. The point is, it's a mere generic greeting, and A is asking for nothing in particular. She is just saying she wants to be in a good relationship with B. In other situations, よろしくお願いします can be translated as "Thank you in advance", "Best regards", "I'm looking forward to working with you", "Say hello to ～" and so on.

Comment: Yeah I get that it's a phrase that isn't easy to translate into English because it has a meaning not found in English that can be captured by just one translation. In the end I went with (paraphrasing) "I'm glad my daughter will be working with you and that we'll be fellow moms together." which I think brings accross the intended meaning/use well enough in this context.

Comment: @4thDimension Looks good to me :)